# set value of variable in main function using a void function

Tags: c++

Why does `num1`'s value equal 0? I do not understand. How come passing `num1` into the `getScore` function and using `cin` does not change the value? How can I change its value based on what is `cin` to `score`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getScore(double);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double num1;
    getScore(num1);
    cout << "NUM 1 got set to " << num1 << endl;
    return 0;
}

void getScore(double score) {
    cout << "whats the score";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "num is " << score << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should have a look at references and pointers

Comment: Why do you use a void function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You passed `num1` by value. That means that `score` is a new variable that had the value from `num1` copied into it.

What you would probably like to happen here is to pass `num1` by reference. That is done by declaring and defining the function like so:

```
void getScore(double&);

void getScore(double& score) {
    cout << "whats the score";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "num is " << score << endl;
}
```

The ampersand (&) means that you are passing a reference to the variable, not a copy of the value stored in the variable. By passing the reference, `score` becomes a sort of 'nickname' for `num1`. This means that setting a value to `score` will really set that value to `num1`.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

Answer (score 2):

A function is commonly understood as evaluating to a value. With that in mind you might rewrite your function to:

```
double getScore(){  // crap and other stuff... + a return }
```

To access the value produced by the return statement in your function, you simply need to assign it.

```
double theInputtedScore = getScore();
```

This function will satisfy the previous assignment.

```
double getScore(){   return 2.71; }
```

When you write

```
getScore(double value).
```

This is commonly understood as the numerical value is an input to your function. You don't want that.

Comment: how will  `double theInputtedScure = getScore();` work when the function takes a double as a parameter.

Comment: @Omar, the point Captain Giraffe is making is that having the function return a value instead of giving it a variable to change is more intuitive for most C++ programmers. Instead of calling `getScore(num1)`, they are suggesting changing that function and calling `num1 = getScore()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an argument by value (like you do here), the function creates a copy of it for itself, so you write into local copy in the getScore(), and that copy is destroyed when the function ends.

See [Passing arguments by value](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/72-passing-arguments-by-value/)